# Are there no class aliases in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Something like this:

```
user:
  targetEntity: User
  inversedBy: posts
  joinColumn:
    name: user_id
    referencedColumnName: id
deleter:
  targetEntity: User
  joinColumn:
    name: deleter_id
    referencedColumnName: id
```

Above we have two relationships to class User, I was wondering if we could do something like targetEntity: Deleter as User

Comment: Why would you need to define a class alias? Referencing User directly is fine.

Comment: @Ocramius because the Entity generator gets confused when I have more than one relationship between two entities

Comment: Don't use the entity generator more than once, it makes no sense and brings only confusion, plus it is not a good pattern to follow when developing. Entity generation is meant to be used just as guideline for a quick start. After that, you should write your code alone. Mappings should follow entities, while the inverse is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So you want Deleters to be Users?  You might go for [Single Table Inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) in that case.  You'll just need to add a discriminator column.

Another common approach for modeling roles a User may have in an application is to have a user_type table or similar.  Then define a many-to-many listing out which roles each User has.  Often times these are tied into privileges and you have to establish hierarchical relationships between said roles, but this is a gross generalization.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. My problem is slightly different, I simply needed the Entity generator (symfony2) to recognize the name of the related entity. for "deleter" it creates wrong setters/getters and I thought aliasing would help this issue, but it might just be a bug in Entity Generator.

Comment: Hmm, I've not used the Entity Generator or the yml approach in sf2.  I've coded up all my entities by hand and used the annotations in my projects.  Perhaps contact the sf2 folks on a mailing list or IRC and let us know if you find the answer; sorry I wasn't of help.